# Flexibility of SoftPot Membrane Potentiometer during the use?

Tags: potentiometer

Does anybody have some information or experiences with the flexibility of Spectra Symbol's [SoftPot Membrane Potentiometer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8681) during the use? Is it possible to partly wind it up on a reel (or something similar) and use the remaining part dynamically without loosing precision and control? Are there "ghost touches" caused by the force/pressure of bending/winding the sensor strip? Or should the sensor always be used in a flattened position?

Thanks for any helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this data sheet it will show you examples on how it is used. https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Flex/SoftPot-Datasheet.pdf

I'd buy a curved one just to make sure, because as it bends, the 2 conductive materials will touch.

Comment: If I helped let me know, it's the first time I have answered a question.

Comment: Oh and also, it does not need to be flat.

Comment: Thanks Mateo for your answer. I know that there are different models of the sensor (length, curve, rotary). But my questions refers to the capability of the measurement accuracy/possibility during the use of extremely roll/winding/bend applications (for example mount it around a small flower tub, or use it as a retractable tape measure). I know that the sensor strips are bendable (as the name and soft material indicates), but I don't know about practical limitation of the maximal winding/bending radius.

Comment: Let me do some research, it will take me sometime, and I will also ask someone who I know that is familiar with it.  Sorry for the misunderstanding :)